# How to override useMemo value and refresh screen?

Tags: reactjs

I have `useMemo` hook as below.

```
  const resultdata = useMemo(() => {
    if (
      perioddata !== null &&
      perioddata !== undefined &&
      initialuser !== undefined
    ) {
      return criteriaSortFunc(resultDateFunc(perioddata));
    }
  }, [perioddata, initialuser]);
```

I returns data Array.

But when I search by keyword, I would like to filter data.

So I have `form` tag.

```
 <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onValid)}>
          <input
            {...register("searchname", {
              required: "이름을 적어주세요.",
              onChange: (text) => {
                setSearchinput(text);
              },
            })}
            type="text"
            placeholder="이름을 검색해주세요."
            className="focus:outline-none focus:border-[#FF2D78] border-2 w-56 border-gray-500 rounded-md py-1 text-center"
          ></input>
          <button className="bg-gray-300 rounded-md py-1 px-3 ml-2">
            검색
          </button>
        </form>
```

And when I put keyword in this form, it will execute `onValid` function.

```
 const onValid = (input) => {
    const searchresult = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < resultdata.length; i++) {
      if (resultdata[i].name === input.searchname) {
        searchresult.push(resultdata[i]);
      }
    }
    resultdata = searchresult
  };
```

This onValid function receive input and filter resultdata by it and returnn output named `searchresult`.

I want to overwrite `resultdata` with this `searchresult`.

SO I use **resultdata = searchresult**.

But screen is not refreshed again with new resultdata.

I check it with `useEffect`.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("bye");
  }, [resultdata]);
```

when `onValid` function executed, log "bye" is not printed.

should I create one more `state` for resultdata?

How can I refresh screen with new resultdata in this case?

---

**ps)**

perioddata is another useMemo hook.

```
  const datasum = useMemo(() => {
    if (
      feedData !== undefined &&
      feedData !== null &&
      poemData !== undefined &&
      poemData !== null &&
      fpLikesData !== undefined &&
      (fpLikesData !== null) & (fpCommentsData !== undefined) &&
      fpCommentsData !== null &&
      pedometerData !== undefined &&
      pedometerData !== null
    ) {
      datasumArray.push(
        ...feedData.seeAdminAllFeeds,
        ...poemData.seeAdminAllPoems,
        ...fpLikesData.seeAdminAllLikes,
        ...fpCommentsData.seeAdminAllComments,
        ...pedometerData.seeAdminAllPedometers
      );
      return datasumArray;
    }
  }, [feedData, poemData, fpLikesData, fpCommentsData, pedometerData]);

  const perioddata = useMemo(() => {
    if (datasum !== null && datasum !== undefined) {
      return datasum.filter(
        (data) =>
          parseInt(data.createdAt) >= startDate.getTime(0, 0, 0, 0) &&
          parseInt(data.createdAt) <= endDate.getTime(23, 59, 59, 999)
      );
    }
  }, [datasum, startDate, endDate]);
```

Comment: What is `perioddata`?

Comment: @ImanpalSingh - I add that on my post

Comment: can you please provide a [minimal reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) like on codesandbox? This helps others to debug and answer faster.